# How to change the lon lat of a raster in R

Tags: raster, latitude-longitude, netcdf, projection, terra

I have a global netcdf with extent 0.5, 362.5, 0.5, 294.5 and centered over the America
I need to change the lon lat of the raster in order to have it centered over the Atlantic but I'm not succeding.
Here are the detail of the raster that I have
[image]

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 294, 362, 106428  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : 0.5, 362.5, 0.5, 294.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA
```

And this is the one that I need to achieve to further crop and extract data:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 681, 1440, 980640  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent     : -180.125, 179.875, -80.125, 90.125  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

[image]

I have tried to rotate the raster and I tried to change the extent but nothing seems to work. (here some attemps...)

```
projection(raster) <- CRS("+init=EPSG:4326")
e <- extent(-294,66, -80.125, 90.125 )
extent(raster) <- e
```

Do you have any suggestion on how to go on?

Answer (score 0):

With `SpatRaster` (from "terra") or Raster* (from "raster") object `x` you can fix the rotated longitude with

```
y <- rotate(x)
```

But note that you have y coordinates between 0.5 and 294.5. That cannot be latitude. Also, your map looks like it uses a Mercator coordinate reference system. Without more information (perhaps a link to the file?) it is difficult to help.